# Define relationship using only Id

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, node.js-typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

I'm having a problem with defining relationship in NestJs, between entities: Users & Orders. I want to bond Orders with only userId -> not the whole entity (its unsave when it comes to authorization). It's my OrdersEntity:

```
@Entity('orders')
export class OrdersEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid') id: string;

  @CreateDateColumn() created: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn() updated: Date;

  @Column('text', { default: StatusEnum.PROCESSING }) status: string;

  // relationships

  @ManyToOne(type => UsersEntity, customer => customer.orders)
  customer: UsersEntity;

  @OneToMany(() => OrderDetailsEntity, orderDetail => orderDetail.order)
  orderDetails: OrderDetailsEntity[];

  // end of relationships
}
```

and it's my UsersEntity:

```
@Entity('users')
export class UsersEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid') id: string;

  @CreateDateColumn() created: Date;

  @Column({
    type: 'text',
    unique: true,
  })
  username: string;

  @Column({
    type: 'text',
  })
  password: string;

  @Column({ type: 'integer', default: 1 }) role: number;

  // relationships

  @OneToMany(type => OrdersEntity, order => order.customer)
  orders: OrdersEntity[];

  // end of relationships
}
```

as you can see, the OrdersEntity uses whole UsersEntity to create bonding. Is there any effective way to bond by the use of customerId (i still want to keep Many to One relationship). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your database schema has nothing to do with authorization. Orders and Users are linked the right way, but your services/controller should take care of returning only the correct content